# Generating a tree structure from string list

Tags: java, html, string, jsp

I have a List of strings with the following format:

```
"levelone.two.three"
"levelone.two.three.node(0)"
"levelone.two.three.node(1)"
"levelone.another"
"aaa.bbb(0).ccc"
"aaa.bbb(1).aaa"
```

etc,

How could I manipulate this in a way which then I could iterate and generate html tree from this?

ex:

- levelone

  - two

    - three

      - node 0
      - node 1
  - another
- aaa

  - bbb 0

    - ccc
  - bbb 1

    - aaa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokenize your strings so have

["levelone", "two", "three"] etc

And then from left to right try inserting in your tree maintaining the current tree node to insert at, starting from root node. If given node has your node to be inserted, don't do anything otherwise insert it.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you fair idea how to achieve this.

*Note: Performance and Actual implementation, you need to do yourself. I just typed the code here*

```
String[] testData = new String[] { "levelone.two.three", "levelone.two.three.node(0)",
                "levelone.two.three.node(1)", "levelone.another", "aaa.bbb(0).ccc", "aaa.bbb(1).aaa" };

List<String[]> splitData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (String data : testData) {
    splitData.add(data.split("\\."));
}

Map<Integer, Set<String>> treeMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Set<String>>();

for (String[] split : splitData) {
     for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
         if (treeMap.get(i) != null) {
             treeMap.get(i).add(split[i]);
         } else {
             Set<String> data = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
             data.add(split[i]);
             treeMap.put(i, data);
         }
     }
}
System.out.println(treeMap); 
// {0=[levelone, aaa], 1=[two, another, bbb(0), bbb(1)], 2=[three, ccc, aaa], 3=[node(0), node(1)]}
```

The final map contains data of each level with it's index as key